# Как прижать дочерний блок к низу родительского?

Tags: html, css

В верстке есть такой блок, фиксированной высоты, в него вложены ещё три блока, верхний и нижний - фиксированной высоты, тот, что посередине - нет.

[image]

Не  могу понять, как прижать нижний блок к низу родительского.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как всегда прижимать footer к низу экрана?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/546490/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b6%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-footer-%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b7%d1%83-%d1%8d%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b0)

Answer (score 7):

У дочернего в стилях пишите:

```
position: absolute;
bottom: 0px;
```

Answer (score 7):

Родительскому установить:

```
position:relative;
padding-bottom:50px;
```

Дочерному:

```
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
```

Answer (score 3):

Хм... Если размеры вам известны, то тут чистая математика. Если только средствами CSS, то можно, например, так сделать:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#wrapper {
  width: 400px;
  height: 600px;
  border: 1px solid #900;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #FFFFFF;
}

#top {
  background: #999;
  height: 70px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 70px;
}

#center {
  background: #CCC;
}

#bottom {
  position: absolute;
  width: 400px;
  top: 551px;
  background: #999;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
}

p {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="top">TOP</div>
  <div id="center">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="bottom">BOTTOM</div>
</div>
```

Если размеры не известны изначально, то тут в помощь JS/jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

[@Heidel](/users/6360/heidel), извините, что с опозданием, вот взгляните - http://jsfiddle.net/Alex83/qktyU/

Если коротко, то блоку обертке задаем:

```
min-height: 100%; /*При этом у body, html { width: 100%; height: 100%;*/
```

А footer выносим за предел блока обертки и устанавливаем ему отрицательный верхний отступ:

```
margin-top: -50px;
```

Comment: Прошу прощения, не верно понял вопрос...

Rules и Deonis правы.

Answer (score 0):

```
#wrapper {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 height: 600px;
}
#center {
 flex-grow: 1;
}
```